# mysql stored procedure Use ROW_COUNT() as condition

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Inside a stored procedure I have some like this:

```
SET @input_var1 = 'some1';
SET @input_var2 = 'some2';

SET @query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column = ?";

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt USING @input_var1;
SET @row_count = ROW_COUNT();
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


IF(@row_count = 0)THEN
    SET @query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column = ?";

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @input_var2;
    SET @row_count = ROW_COUNT();
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;    
END IF;
```

The problem:

**@row_count always return -1**

Espected:

- @row_count = 0 ... if empty result
- @row_count = 1 ... if result is one row
- @row_count > 0 ... if result is not empty (one or many rows)

Comment: `ROW_COUNT()` always returns `-1` for SELECT statements. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count - Try `FOUND_ROWS()` or use an EXISTS query.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel you saved my life :) ... I have tried `FOUND_ROWS()` now  and work as espected.